# Why does HTTP request doesn't execute after IF Controller

Tags: jmeter

I'm kind of new with JMeter and I have the following problem.
When `If controller` executes, the next block after it doesn't being executed in my example it is `Send Document`.

My task is to read the CSV file, check if the previous value equals to current value from the CSV file, in case if they are not equal I need to make a request to get a token, and `Send Document` block must execute no matter if `IF Controller` is `true` or `false`

How can i achieve this?

[image]

Comment: What is the condition in the While Controller? "When If controller executes" means when condition is true?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 options:

1. The request under the If Controller fails somehow and you have `Stop Test` as the action to be taken after a Sampler error in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

   [image]

   if this is the case and you want to run the 2nd request in any case - set it to `Continue`
2. You have `Stop thread on EOF` set to `true` in the CSV Data Set Config

   [image]

   if this is the case the test will be stopped when the CSV file runs out of values. If this is the case - set it to `false` as well as `Recycle on EOF` and put the whole block under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) and use something like `${__javaScript("${your_variable_from_csv}" != "<EOF>",)}`  as the condition
3. If I'm not telepathic enough and the reason is not in 2 listed above - take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it normally contains sufficient information to get to the bottom of the issue.